# Let $R$ be a relation. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two sets. Then $R[A] \setminus R[B]$ $\subseteq$ $R[A\setminus B]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I know how to prove something is a subset of another but I’m not sure how to use the properties of the image to prove $x$ is not in the image of $B.$

Comment: What is $R[A]$?

Comment: First of all, you need a Cartesian product if a relation is binary, if it's unary then don't.

Comment: @DonThousand, the $R$-relation image of $A$ $$R[A]=\{y : \exists x\in A~. \langle x, y\rangle \in R\}$$

Comment: Take a look at non injective functions for example, which are a special case.

Comment: The [tag:proof-explanation] tag is for when you need a specific proof to be explained. Also, please make the body of your question self-contained, the title and body should be able to stand on their own.

Answer (score 1):

It's just symbols.

Let $A,B\subset X$ then $R[A]= \{x\in X| (x,a)\in R,$ for some $a\in A\}$

so if $m \in R[A]\setminus R[b]$ then $m\in R[a]$ but $m\not \in R[b]$.

$m\in R[a]$ so there is an $a_m\in A$ so that $(m,a_m) \in R$ while $m\not \in R[b]$ so there is no $b\in B$ so that $(m,b)\in R$. Which means, as $(m,a_m)$ *is* in $R$ than $a_m$ can not be in $B$.

So $a_m\in A$ but $a_m \not \in B$ so $a_m \in A\setminus B$.

So there is an $a_m\in A\setminus B$ so that $(m,a_m)\in R$ so $m\in R[A\setminus B]$.

So $R[A]\setminus R[b]\subset R[A\setminus B]$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Graham's clarification is correct, the left-hand side $R[A] \setminus R[B]$ is the set of all $x$ such that $x \mathrel{R} y$ for some $y$ in $A$, but $x \mathrel{R} z$ is true for no $z \in B$.

The right-hand side $R[A\setminus B]$ is the set of all $x$ such that $x \mathrel{R} y$ for some $y$ that is in $A$ but not in $B$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Shouldn't it be  'for some $y$ that is in $A$ nur not in $B$

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya You are correct.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

The $\def\R{\mathop{\rm R}}\R$-relation image of $A$ is the set of elements related by some element in $A$.

$$\R[A]=\{y : \exists x\in A~. \langle x, y\rangle \in R\}\\ =\{y:\exists x\in A~.~xRy\}$$

So for any $c$, we have $c\in\R[A]$ if and only if $\exists x~.(x\in A\wedge x\R c)$

Likewise for any $c$, we have $c\notin\R[B]$ if and only if $\forall x~.(x\in B\to \neg x\R c)$

---

You seek to show that $\R[A]\smallsetminus\R[B]\subseteq\R[A\smallsetminus B]$

Thus you need to show that  $\forall z~(z\in\R[A]\smallsetminus\R[B]\to z\in\R[A\smallsetminus B])$, by the definition for subset.

---

> I’m not sure how to use the properties of the image to prove $x$ is not in the image of $B$.

The subproof is a Proof of Negation.  Assume that it is in $B$ aiming to derive a contradiction.

Use the above to help fill out the rest of this proof.

- Begin

  - Take *any* $c$

    - Assume that $c\in\R[A]\smallsetminus\R[B]$
    - $c\in\R[A]$ and $c\notin\R[B]$
    - $\exists x~.(x\in A\wedge x\R c)$ and $\forall x~.(x\in B\to \neg x\R c)$

      - Take *some* $a$ such that $a\in A$ and $a\R c$

        - Assume $a\in B$
        - :
        - :
        - Contradiction!
      - Therefore $a\notin B$
      - :
    - :
    - :
    - Thus $c\in\R[A\smallsetminus B]$
  - $c\in\R[A]\smallsetminus\R[B]\to c\in\R[A\smallsetminus B]$
- $\forall z~.(z\in\R[A]\smallsetminus\R[B]\to z\in\R[A\smallsetminus B])$
- $\R[A]\smallsetminus\R[B]\subseteq\R[A\smallsetminus B]$
- End.